# Using ZFS created on FreeBSD

Tags: mount, 20.04, hard-drive, zfs

The motherboard in my NAS that ran FreeBSD (I think it was fairly updated, at least a 12., but not one where they had switched to the ZFS implementation used bu Ubuntu) died, so now I have 6 disks housing a zpool (using raidz2) with a lot of data (~20 TB I think).

I've been thinking about switching to ubuntu on that box for some time (I've used Debian since before Ubuntu was created, but Ubuntu comes with a kernel supporting ZFS, so for this box I thnk Ubuntu is a better choice than Debian).

If I get a new motherboard with enough SATA ports, and put in 8 disks, installing Ubuntu (it would probably be 20.04, even though 20.10 is close, but LTS matters) on a mirror of the two new, will I be to use the ZFS'es on the old disks (from FreeBSD)? One issue I see is that the filesystems have mountpoints according to the (Free)BSD standard with home directories somewhere in `/usr/users`. Some recovery work is acceptable (the shutdown probably wasn't very clean, but it had been several days (perhaps even weeks) since I had written data to it, so the risk of data loss is probably small).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you just have to download it from the official repositories with apt.

```
sudo apt install zfs
```

Setting up a RAIDZ2 requires running:

```
sudo zpool create pool-henrik raidz2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh
```

By default, Ubuntu will mount the disk pool in the root of the operating system /.

So if we want to access it and its data, we must go to the:

```
 /pool-henrik/directory.
```

In case you want to add disks to the pool, it is done with the command:

```
sudo zpool add pool-henrik /dev/sdx
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new pool, is that also the way to recover something that is already on the disks?